# python: why can't a series's dtype is datetime64[ns] user apply(lambda x:x-x.max())/np.timedelta64(1,'D') but (x-x.max)/np.timedelta64(1,'D')

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pd.Series` as follows:

[image: picutre 1:a is a series of datetime64[ns]]

I want to calculate difference value between `a` and `a.max` and at the same time transfer the difference value format to `float`. I can use picture 2 to do what I want, but why does the approach in picture 3 fail?

**Picture 2 (correct):**
[image: picture 2:b code]

**Picture 3 (wrong):**
[image: picture 3:a wrong code]

**Error message:**
[image: picture 4:the error prompt]

Comment: place your code and data instead of pictures.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `a.apply(lambda x:x-x.max())/np.timedelta64(1,'D')` is that you are trying to get the `max` from a Timestamp (i.e. `x`). However, as mentioned in the error message, a "'Timestamp' object is not callable". So, in this particular case, it is trying to tell you that a Timestamp, understandably, does not have a function `max`. You are looking for `a.max()` instead of `x.max()`.

**Data**

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = [datetime(1997,1,1),datetime(1997,1,12),datetime(1998,5,28),
        datetime(1997,12,12),datetime(1998,1,3)]

a = pd.Series(data, index=range(1,6), name='user_id')

print(a)

1   1997-01-01
2   1997-01-12
3   1998-05-28
4   1997-12-12
5   1998-01-03
Name: user_id, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

**Code**

```
# using `pd.Timedelta` avoids having to import `np`
b = (a-a.max())/pd.Timedelta(days=1)
print(b)

1   -512.0
2   -501.0
3      0.0
4   -167.0
5   -145.0
Name: user_id, dtype: float64

# use `a.max()` instead of `x.max()`:
c = a.apply(lambda x:x-a.max())/pd.Timedelta(days=1)
print(b.equals(c))
# True

# refactored solution:
d = a.sub(a.max()).dt.days
print(d)

1   -512
2   -501
3      0
4   -167
5   -145
Name: user_id, dtype: int64

# chain `.astype(float)`, if you specifically want `floats`:
print(a.sub(a.max()).dt.days.astype(float).equals(b))
# True
```